# I’ve stolen money from my dad, and I want to pay it back though he’s the only one I have left but what if he dies, what do I do then?

Tags: halal-haram, forgiveness, death

I have for some while now been taking some money from my dad, and he doesn’t know, but how do I repay him if he dies I don’t have a job or anything rn and my intention is not bad when using this money I just don’t have money to take care of myself.

Comment: Why don't you ask your dad for forgiveness? Is he brute, unloving and unforgiving?